# non-numeric character was found where numeric was expected

Tags: database

select * from dual where sysdate<=to_date(to_date('2017/12/10','yyyy/mm/dd'),'MM/DD/YYYY'); show error non-numeric character was found  where numeric was expected

Comment: What is the purpose of the outer `to_date`?  The inner `to_date` returns a date.  just compare that to `sysdate`.

Comment: its not work select * from dual where sysdate<=(to_date('2017/12/10','yyyy/mm/dd'),'MM/DD/YYYY');

Comment: can u send me query which works??

Comment: You need to get rid of the whole thing, function name and paramters. `select * from dual where sysdate <= to_date('2017/12/10','yyyy/mm/dd');`

Comment: thanks. its customer issues which gave us wrong query